Isekai/reincarnation manga where the main character is transported inside a game with his sister
From what I can remember, the main character (MC) and his sister are killed and both of them are transported/reincarnated inside a game the MC played.
In that game, the MC was a top Summoner/Tamer class player, but his account was deleted by his killer, who was his foster parent.
He will use all his knowledge about the game to get stronger and find his sister.
If I remember correctly, in the first few chapters, he stayed in the tutorial to farm experience points.
The manga was mostly black and white.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Mostly black and white

This is The Invincible Summoner Who Crawled Up from Level 1.

After losing his father in a tragic accident, Shinobu Iijima and his younger sister Megumi are taken in by their father’s old friend, Ayumu. Shinobu works hard in the hopes of starting a new life for himself. Megumi, and a mobile game called La Vita Online, are the only things keeping him afloat. One day, Ayumu reveals his true intentions of tearing Shinobu down and getting his hands on Megumi. But just after Shinobu learns that Ayumu deleted all of his game data in La Vita, their high-rise apartment catches on fire and Shinobu falls to his death, Megumi in tow. He wakes up in a strange new world... and realizes he’s been reincarnated into the world of La Vita Online. An announcement from the devs tells him that Ayumu is already there, and a countdown to Megumi’s arrival is ticking. Shinobu vows to protect Megumi after she arrives at any cost, even if it means he has to crawl his way up from level 1 to fend off all the other reincarnated players.

After their biological parents died, Shinobu Iijima and his younger sister Megumi were taken in by their father's friend, Ayumi Imabayashi, who became their foster father.



Four years later, Shinobu was one of the top players in an MMORPG called La Vita Online, but learned that Ayumi had deleted his account data and created his own account in the game. Shinobu, Megumi and Ayumi are then all killed by a fire in their apartment building and transmigrated into the game. Shinobu wakes up alone in the tutorial with the class of 'Summoner' and grinds his way up from level 1 to 72, before completing the tutorial and setting off to find his sister.




Thank you, this is it, been looking like crazy, Thanks
